# Scrapy - can't download files

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I can't get Scrapy's file download pipeline to work. There are no errors in the log. What am I missing?

** I know `fspider.py` is not complete for running the spider -- I'm just testing `parse_list` using the `scrapy parse` debugger for now

```
fspider.py:

import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider

class FSpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = 'fsp'
  allowed_domains = 'hdr.undp.org'
  start_urls = ['http://hdr.undp.org/en/2016-report/download']

def parse_list(self, response):
  links = [response.urljoin(link) for link in response.css('li ::attr(href)').extract()]
  for link in links:
    if 'overview' in link.lower():
      yield {'file_urls': link}
```

And in `settings.py` I have added:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1}
FILES_STORE = 'files'
```

When I run the `parse` debugger, I get:

```
>>> STATUS DEPTH LEVEL 1 <<<
# Scraped Items  ------------------------------------------------------------
[{'file_urls': 'http://hdr.undp.org/sites/default/files/HDR2016_EN_Overview_Web.pdf'},
 {'file_urls': 'http://hdr.undp.org/sites/default/files/HDR2016_FR_Overview_Web.pdf'},
 {'file_urls': 'http://hdr.undp.org/sites/default/files/HDR2016_SP_Overview_Web.pdf'},
 {'file_urls': 'http://hdr.undp.org/sites/default/files/HDR2016_AR_Overview_Web.pdf'},
 {'file_urls': 'http://hdr.undp.org/sites/default/files/HDR2016_RU_Overview_Web.pdf'},
 {'file_urls': 'http://hdr.undp.org/sites/default/files/hdr2016_cn_overview_web.pdf'}]

# Requests  -----------------------------------------------------------------
[]
```

...but nothing has been downloaded.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: in the `parse` function, the link has to be passed as a list:

```
  yield {'file_urls': [link]}
```